# ZK UI update on Database data changes

Tags: zk

How can I update data on UI when someting changes on database?
I want that my UI automatically update data when I changes record on my database (with a common database viewer) like Facebook does when someone friend publish something on the clipboard (without refresh)

Answer (score 0):

You can use polling or pushing.

For pushing you could extend SelectorComposer
and apply to your zul

```
public class ComposerPush extends SelectorComposer<Component>  {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
// wire components
@Wire
ZHighCharts chartComp;

// Basic Line
private SimpleExtXYModel dataChartModel = new SimpleExtXYModel();


 public void startWorker() {
            final Desktop desktop = Executions.getCurrent().getDesktop();
            if (desktop.isServerPushEnabled()) {
            } else {
                desktop.enableServerPush(true);
                if(timer != null)timer.cancel();
                timer = new Timer();
                timer.schedule(databaseCheck(), 0, 5000);
            }
        }

    private TimerTask databaseCheck() { 
            return new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    updateInfo();
                }
            };
        }

        private void updateInfo() {
            try {
                 Desktop desktop = chartComp.getDesktop();
                if(desktop == null) {
                    timer.cancel();
                    return;
                }

                Executions.activate(desktop);
                try {

                          **<your code in here>**

                } finally {
                    Executions.deactivate(desktop);
                }
            } catch (DesktopUnavailableException ex) {
                System.out.println("Desktop currently unavailable");
                timer.cancel();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("The server push thread interrupted");
                timer.cancel();
            }


        }
```

Comment: @Tex'N'Duet see my additions, you extend a composer